# Add text property, when global-font-lock mode is on

Tags: font-lock, text-properties

I am trying to set the foreground color for first line in my buffer which has `global-font-lock` ON.

Buffer contents -

```
(ignore) 
(add-text-properties 1 8
                                         '(:foreground "red"))
;;since add-text-properties didn't work, i tried with add-face-text-property
(add-face-text-property 1 8 '(:foreground "red"))
```

When i do `eval-buffer`, i like to see the first line, `(ignore)` made red. But it is not so. I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242269/changing-text-appearance-in-emacs-overlays-work-text-properties-dont) to know the function, `add-text-properties` doesn't work when font-lock mode is ON.

Is there a way one can change the properties for text that lies between a start and end point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `font-lock-mode` is in use, you can use the [`font-lock-face`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) property instead of `face`.

> (add-text-properties 1 8 '(font-lock-face (:foreground "red")))

Comment: what if you want the face to stay but also want to apply something like an underline?

Comment: Interesting. You could set font-lock-face to the current value of face plus what you want to add. (defun add-to-font-locked-face (b e v) (put-text-property b e 'font-lock-face (cons v (get-text-property b 'face)))). Then (add-to-font-locked-face 1 11 '(:underline t)). Seems to work well if you add to a whole font locked word.