# Add invisible text property in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, text-properties, visibility

Suppose I have a function like `my-make-invisible`, where `my-re` is some regexp:

```
(defun my-make-invisible ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward my-re nil t)
      (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0)
                           (match-end 0)
                           '(invisible t)))))
```

This function just makes each portion of buffer content that matches `my-re` invisible: it works in all major modes I've tried, but not in org-mode.

Is there an easy way to achieve the same in org-mode?

(Note: adding other properties, like faces or displays, with a function like the one above does work in org-mode.  It seems that the problem is only adding invisibility)

I have the same problem if I try to make things invisible by adding them to `buffer-invisibility-spec`. Except for when the buffer is in org-mode, the following makes the first three characters in the buffer invisible:

```
(progn (add-text-properties 1 3 '(invisible hide-this-stuff))
       (add-to-invisibility-spec '(hide-this-stuff)))
```

If I do it in org-mode, `hide-this-stuff` will show up in the value of `buffer-invisibility-spec` but this has no effect whatsoever as far as the visibility of those first three characters.

Comment: AFAIK, the text property conflicts with what `font-lock-mode` does and since the latter runs in the background, it wins. You can see that that is the case by toggling it off: `M-x font-lock-mode`. I would guess that you need to do search-based fontification in this case, instead of search based text-property setting. See the `Font lock` section in the Emacs manual and references therein, particularly the reference to `Search-based fontification` in the Elisp manual. You can start with `C-h i g(emacs)Font lock` and go from there.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/add-text-property-when-global-font-lock-mode-is-on) will help, although in my limited experiments I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Thanks @NickD ! This put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using **overlay properties** instead of **text properties** to avoid conflicts. You can specify a `priority` to override any exiting overlays.

Modifying your example to this will make make invisible all instances of `my-re` regexp:

```
(defun my-make-invisible (my-re)
  (interactive "sRE Search Term: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward my-re nil t)
      (setq invisible-overlay (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
      (overlay-put invisible-overlay 'invisible t))))
```

There are a few differences when using [overlay properties vs text properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html), which may or may not work for your use case. Overlays will not transfer when copy/pasting, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same in Org mode even using text properties by adding your own folding specification (see the docstring of variable `org-fold-core--specs` for details) and then call `org-fold-core-region`:

```lisp
(defvar my-re "my regex pattern")

(org-fold-core-add-folding-spec 'my-invisible nil)

(defun my-make-invisible (&optional unfold)
  "Make all matches in buffer for regex `my-re' invisible.
When UNFOLD is non-nil make them visible instead."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward my-re nil t)
      (org-fold-core-region (match-beginning 0)
                            (match-end 0)
                            (if unfold nil t)
                            'my-invisible))))

(my-make-invisible)
```

The commentary section of the built-in Emacs package `org-fold-core.el` provides a good explanation of how this works. Note that `org-fold-core--specs` is buffer-local, so you need to call `org-fold-core-add-folding-spec` in each buffer where you want to use it, for example by adding the call to `org-mode-hook`.

Also note that it is indeed `font-lock-mode` that prevents this from working by just adding text properties, as can be confirmed by turning off `font-lock-mode`.