# How to keep existing text-property decoration while using font-lock?

Tags: faces, font-lock, text-properties, coloring

I tried to use text-property to decorate specific texts as well as automatically color tab characters in a text-mode buffer, but didn't find a way to realize them at the same time.

This is my try:

1. Start Emacs with the option -Q:

   ```
   foo@bar:~$ emacs -Q
   ```
2. Open a new text file and an existing C file:

   [image: Open a new text file and an existing C file]
3. Copy a colored text from the c-mode buffer (M-w : kill-ring-save) to the text-mode buffer (C-y : yank).

   [image]

   The pasted text at this time is colored the same.
4. Then, make a font-lock rule to set backgound color of tab characters in the text mode buffer to make tab visible.

   ```lisp
   (font-lock-add-keywords nil              ; current buffer
                           `(("\\(\t+\\)"   ; Tab
                            1
                           '((t (:background "gray")))
                           prepend)))
   ```

   [image]

   While all tab characters get colored as expected, the pasted decorated texts become back to default uncolored look.

   I want only the tab background to be colored, while keeping existing texts decorated.
   And, I want to make it by 2 strokes, copy and paste (M-w and C-y).

   Newly copied texts to the text buffer also no longer keep the original colors.

   [image]

How can I make use of font-lock feature, as well as keeping existing static text-property faces in a buffer?

Emacs 27.1, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add text property, when global-font-lock mode is on](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/add-text-property-when-global-font-lock-mode-is-on)

Comment: See also this question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27185/105

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After #4 too, I want to do #2 and #3 several times, keeping own or original text-property faces, and even insert many tabs. Given that, after #4, replacing face with font-lock-face works for #2, but for #3, original text property faces already disappeared on the current buffer befor replacing. So, I believe other measures are also necessary.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please specify a step-by-step recipe to reproduce your problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). *At each step* show exactly what you do, say what you expect to see as the effect, and what you see instead.

Comment: @ Drew Thank you for pointing this out. I will correct it.

Comment: I rewrote the question to clarify what I ask.

Comment: Thanks; much clearer. Understand that (1) different modes have different font-lock rules and (2) any non-font-lock ad-hoc highlighting you do can get overridden by font-lock. The Q&A I pointed you to is exactly about this (#2).

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I understood that converting/copying existing face properties into font-lock-face properties will meet my demand.

But actually I have no idea how to realize the conversion with my elisp skill.

Comment: For example, in the step 4, in order to copy a code snippet from the c-mode buffer to the text buffer with colors, I'd need to implement an elisp function that converts source string's face properties into font-lock-face at the destination text, probably right after the text is put into or right before popped from kill-ring. Maybe should I use advice-add? It sounds to me like a so daunting task, given that there are complex functions that handle kill-ring such as C-w, M-w, C-y and/or M-y... Could anybody give me a hint or alternative ideas?